# How to upload a string to s3 as gzip Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, gzip

I have a node.JS program that reads array of string from Redis.
I need to upload this string to my bucket in AWS s3, in a GZIP format, without creating a gzip file locally before uploading.

Basically I want kind of streaming the read strings from Redis to s3 bucket gzip compressed.

In addition to the above problem, I'd like to know what is the efficient and recommended way to program in this way, so the file that will be stored in S3 will be max 64 MB, and incase there is additional data, additional file is created (limited to max 64MB as well).
In the below example I show how I read from the Redis key the value to be stored in s3 gzip limit to 64 MB:

```
client.lrange(key, 0, -1, (error, arrayStringValue) => {
            if (arrayStringValue == null || !arrayStringValue.length) {
                client.del(key);
                return console.log("removing key, no values");
            }
            if (error) reject(error);
            console.log("finish iterating");
            impressionsRecorded = true;
            //compress 
            uploadToS3(arrayStringValue, "bucket/key", null);
```

Basically what i'm missing is the right implementation of the **uploadToS3** method

Comment: Is [`AWS.S3.putObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) from the JavaScript SDK not "the right implementation" ...?  Not sure what you are looking for, if not that.

Comment: Does it support uploading in gzip format ?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  *You* still need to do the gzipping, but since `var params = { Body: <Binary String>,` uploading the (binary) gzip data isn't a problem.  You would also probably want to set `ContentEncoding: 'gzip'` so clients understand what to do with the data. (This doesn't *cause* the content to be gzipped, it just sets `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response headers when the object is fetched, which most clients will use to automatically/transparently decompress the payload.)

Comment: I'd appreciate if you will answer with code sample, I will test and confirm answer :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had to solve the same problem. Here is my solution in Node.js.

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');

const uncompressedString = 'Hi there';

const compressedStringAsBuffer = zlib.gzipSync(uncompressedString);

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      Body: compressedStringAsBuffer,
      Key: 'my-compressed-string.txt.gzip', // .gzip isn't required
      ContentType: 'text/plain', // change the ContentType if you want to serve HTML, CSS, JS, etc.
      ContentEncoding: 'gzip' // that's important
    };

await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am extending the answer provided by Jan for the IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS):

Let's take care of credentials for IBM COS:

```
var config = {
endpoint: 's3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
apiKeyId: 'put your key here',
serviceInstanceId: 'put serviceInstanceID here',
};

//bucket settings
var evaluation_bucket_name = 'evaluation.data'
```

Now let's assume you have a string consist of the data you want to compress and submit to IBM COS (your data can be user data in JSON format or any other format). Here I have a variable called `aggregated_records` that is in JSON format.

```
toBeSubmitted = JSON.stringify(aggregated_records)
const zlib = require('zlib');
const toBeSubmittedCompressed = zlib.gzipSync(toBeSubmitted);
var object_name = 'aggregated_records.json.gzip'
```

Now, let's submit it to IBM COS.

```
CreateObject(evaluation_bucket_name, object_name, toBeSubmittedCompressed)
        .then(function () {
            console.log(`###The object has been successfully submitted to the IBM Object Storage!`)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', util.inspect(err))
        });
```

Now, let's take a look at the submissin function

```
function CreateObject(bucket_name, object_name, object_content) {
    console.log('Creating object');
    return cos.putObject({
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: object_name,
        Body: object_content,
        ContentEncoding: 'gzip'  //important for submitting compressed files
    }).promise();
}
```